# Git bash can't find executable in different drive when using windows style path

Tags: windows, path, git-bash

Problem: If current directory is not C: then git bash can't find executable despite setting correct path variable.

Explanation:
I'm trying to use conan virtual environment which extends PATH env variable automatically with location to compiler toolchain. For example it adds cmake location as follows:

```
PATH="C:\.conan\2c7qf6\1\cmake-3.14.3-win64-x64/bin"${PATH+:$PATH}
```

My source code is saved in drive D:. From there, when I try to execute cmake, I get error:

```
bash: cmake: command not found
```

But if I switch to drive C:, the error doesn't occur.

Also, modifying path from `C:\.conan\2c7qf6\1\cmake-3.14.3-win64-x64/bin` to  `/c/.conan/2c7qf6/1/cmake-3.14.3-win64-x64/bin`") also fixes the error but I can't use this solution since PATH is supposed to be handled by conan and not edited manually.

Is there something wrong with my environment or is this an issue with git bash?

Thanks for your help in advance!